# SQLAlchemy Declarative: Adding a static text attribute to a column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bottle

I am using: SQLAlchemy 0.7.9 and Python 2.7.3 with Bottle 0.11.4.  I am an amateur at python.

I have a class (with many columns) derived from declarative base like this:

```
class Base(object):

     @declared_attr
     def __tablename__(cls):
             return cls.__name__.lower()

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

     def to_dict(self):
             serialized = dict((column_name, getattr(self, column_name))
                     for column_name in self.__table__.c.keys())
             return serialized

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


class Case(Base):

     version                 = Column(Integer)
     title                   = Column(String(32))
     plausible_dd            = Column(Text)
     frame                   = Column(Text)
     primary_task            = Column(Text)
     secondary_task          = Column(Text)
     eval_objectives         = Column(Text)
     ...
```

I am currently using this 'route' in Bottle to dump out a row/class in json like this:

```
@app.route('/<name>/:record')
def default(name, record, db):
    myClass = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], name)
    parms = db.query(myClass).filter(myClass.id == record)
    result = json.dumps(([parm.to_dict() for parm in parms]))
    return result
```

My first question is: How can I have each column have some static text that I can use as a proper name such that I can iterate over the columns and get their values AND proper names?  For example:

```
class Case(Base):
     version    = Column(Integer)
     version.pn = "Version Number"
```

My second question is: Does the following do what I am looking for?  I have seen examples of this, but I don't understand the explanation.

Example from [sqlalchemy.org](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#customizing-column-properties):

```
      id = Column("some_table_id", Integer)
```

My interpretation of the example:

```
      version   = Column("Version Number", Integer)
```

Obviously I don't want a table column to be created.  I just want the column to have an "attribute" in the generic sense.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just realized that I could have a row that contains the proper names.  I am still interested in seeing if that functionality could be put in the model though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[info](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.info) dictionary could be used for that.  In your model class define it like this:

```
class Case(Base):
    version = Column(Integer, info={'description': 'Version Number'})
```

Then it can accessed as the table column property:

```
desc = Case.__table__.c.version.info.get('description', '<no description>')
```

---

**Update**

Here's one way to iterate through all the columns in the table and get their names, values and descriptions.  This example uses dict comprehension, which is available since Python 2.7.

```
class Case(Base):
    # Column definitions go here...

    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: (getattr(self, c.name), c.info.get('description'))
                for c in self.__table__.c}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  I've been trying, but I can't figure out how to iterate them and get them into a dict.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Still getting used to Python. :)